# Add item into array instead of overriding the current value with the new value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to add new items into array instead of overriding the current value with the new value. I'm using .push() which should add the item every time it maps through the array. Any Ideas?

```js
const searchChips = [
{value: "string"}, {value: "test"}
];
const query = {
        bool: {
            filter: []
        }
    };
const searchQuery = {
  query_string: {
    query: ""
  }
};
searchChips.map(chip => {
  console.log(chip);
  const key = "query";
  searchQuery.query_string[key] = chip.value;
  query.bool.filter.push(searchQuery);
});
console.log(query);
```

[image]

Comment: A `.map()` operation should always return an object, so you're using it wrong first of all. Try using `.forEach()` instead

Comment: There are no arrays in your snippet. You're making us guess at what you're trying to do. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for advice on making good questions.

Comment: `ReferenceError: searchChips is not defined`

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: Just added more code

Comment: @melpomene added more code

Comment: @LloydFrancis i tried using foreach() but it does the same thing.

Comment: You are pushing into the array outside the `.map()` function. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are pushing into `query.bool.filter` outside the `.map()` function. Try this.

```
const searchChips = [{ value: "string" }, { value: "test" }];
const query = {
  bool: {
    filter: []
  }
};

searchChips.forEach(chip => {
  const key = "query";
  const searchQuery = {
    query_string: {
      query: ""
    }
  };
  searchQuery.query_string[key] = chip.value;
  query.bool.filter.push(searchQuery);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(query));
```

Comment: it gives me 2 objects with each object having the same value

Comment: Updated my answer, moved `searchQuery`to inside `.forEach()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the same query since you are dealing with the same exact reference to the `searchQuery`. Instead of this try having it as a function which returns an object:

```js
const searchChips = [{
  value: "string"
}, {
  value: "test"
}];

const query = {
  bool: {
    filter: []
  }
};

let sq = (query) => ({
  query_string: {query}
});

searchChips.map(chip => query.bool.filter.push(sq(chip.value)));
console.log(query);
```

This will return to you the 2 filters each with different values for `query_string` since now the function will return an entirely new object instead of you dealing with the same reference.